# Displaying input back to a user - javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have found several questions with answers on how to do this, but I think my problem is an interesting one. I am trying to have a user enter in their name in a text box, then once they hit a button it will display it back to them.

This is the code I have:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Side Bar test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css" />
</head>

<body>
    <div id="sideWrapper">
        <p id="wrapper"><label for="name">Name: <input type="text" name="name" id="name"></p>
        <button onclick="display();">Submit</button>
        </br>

        <div id="playerName">

        </div>
    </div>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    var input = document.getElementById("name").value;

    function display() {
        document.getElementById("playerName").innerHTML = "<p>Player: " + input + "</p>";
    }
</script>
```

When the `document.getElementById("name").value` is called, it only takes whatever was in the text field when the page **first** loaded. Trying to update it after and clicking the button doesn't work. So, if you type "John Doe" in the field and then reload the page and hit the button, it will display John Doe. But if you try to change it, it doesn't work. I have tried moving the script to the `<head>` but that only makes it undefined.

How can I make it so the `display()` function sees what the user types in the box and updates it to print it out to the screen?

**EDIT**: Fixed the code by moving the input line into the function body.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function display() {
        var input = document.getElementById("name").value;
        document.getElementById("PlayerName").innerHTML = "<p>Player: " + input + "</p>";
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Put the  `var input = document.getElementById("name").value;` inside the function.  Essentially, that code runs the second the page is loaded, long before any input is given.  You want to grab that value after the button is clicked, so put it inside the function.

Comment: well i was on answering looks you go the answer , see this fiddles https://jsfiddle.net/zcv1awwt/  just put script code in body

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put your declaration of `input` inside your `display` function.

```
function display() {
    var input = document.getElementById("name").value;
    document.getElementById("playerName").innerHTML = "<p>Player: " + input + "</p>";
}
```

As you currently have it, the value of `input` is stored when the page is loaded, so it does not update automatically.

Answer (score 1):

The `input = document.getElementById("name").value;` should be inside the function `display()`, because you will always set it it's initial value (empty).

Answer (score 1):

You're problem is that this: `var input = document.getElementById("name").value;`
fires immediately when the program loads.

To fix this, do this:

```
function display() {
    var input = document.getElementById("name").value;
    document.getElementById("playerName").innerHTML = "<p>Player: " + input + "</p>";
}
```

That way, the input variable is assigned the current value of the input element each time the function is called.

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pg1muegs/) to show that the `input` variable assignment fires when the page is loading.  I added a default value to the input to show that no matter what you change it to afterwards, the value is always what the default is.